# How to get reference of a specific child button in ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have a class which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and I've created a button on each group of it. There are a total of 6 groups. In the adapter on `getChildView` I want to change the text of the button on a specific position (e.g. 2).

[image]

I've heard about the tag function but I don't know how to use it for my case. How is it possible to change the `button text` on a `specific child`?

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int position = groupPosition + 1;

    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            allQuestions = MyConstants.QUESTIONS_1;
            break;
        case 2:
            allQuestions = MyConstants.QUESTIONS_2;
            break;
        case 3:
            allQuestions = MyConstants.QUESTIONS_3;
            break;
        case 4:
            allQuestions = MyConstants.QUESTIONS_4;
            break;
        case 5:
            allQuestions = MyConstants.QUESTIONS_5;
            break;
        case 6:
            allQuestions = MyConstants.QUESTIONS_6;
            break;
    }

    int correctQuestions = MyDatabase.getInstance(context).getCorrectQuestions(position).getCount();
    int wrongQuestions = MyDatabase.getInstance(context).getWrongQuestions(position).getCount();
    int openQuestions = allQuestions - correctQuestions - wrongQuestions;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    tv_questionOpenResult = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_questionOpenResult);
    tv_correctAmountResult = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_correctAmountResult);
    tv_wrongAmountResult = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_wrongAmountResult);

    bt_openQuestions = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_openQuestions);
    bt_openQuestions.setTag(position);
    bt_correctQuestions = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_correctQuestions);
    bt_wrongQuestions = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_wrongQuestions);


    if (allQuestions == correctQuestions) {
        bt_openQuestions.setEnabled(true);
        bt_openQuestions.setText("Test");
        allCorrect = true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.adapter;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;

import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;



import com.example.R;
import com.example.model.filter_Item;


import org.json.JSONObject;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Filter_ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    ArrayList<String> _listDataHeader;




    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<filter_Item>> list_child = new HashMap<>();
    private HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;
    public static ArrayList<filter_Item> selected_list_child = new ArrayList<>();
    private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;



    public Filter_ExpandableAdapter(Context _context, ArrayList<String> _listDataHeader, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<filter_Item>> list_child) {
        this._context = _context;
        this._listDataHeader = _listDataHeader;
        this.list_child = list_child;
        mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer, boolean[]>();

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return list_child.get(groupPosition).size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return list_child.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);


    }


    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_row_filter, null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filter_name);
        lblListHeader.setText(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).toString());

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
        final int mChildPosition = childPosition;


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row_filter, null);
            childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
            childViewHolder.select_item = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.select_checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(R.layout.child_row_filter, childViewHolder);
        } else {
            childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.layout.child_row_filter);
        }

        childViewHolder.select_item.setText("" + list_child.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getLc_sub_name());
        childViewHolder.select_item.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);


        if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(mGroupPosition)) {
            boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
            childViewHolder.select_item.setChecked(getChecked[mChildPosition]);

        }
        else {
            boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(mGroupPosition)];
            mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
            childViewHolder.select_item.setChecked(false);
        }


        childViewHolder.select_item.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                    getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                    mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
                    selected_list_child.add(list_child.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
                }
                else
                {
                    boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                    getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                    mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
                    selected_list_child.remove(list_child.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
    private class ChildViewHolder {
        CheckBox select_item;

    }




}
```

Try this  code...